# Add some user user meta data as order meta data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

A Customer creates a subscription and tells me what he requires via WooCommerce. The requirements are stored inside of the user profile using the user meta data. When he updates this in the WooCommerce my account area on the front end, it updates it fine within the Wordpress customer profile. No problems there.

The problem i have is, When he updates the requirements via a custom field inside of the WooCommerce account area on the front end, the subscription keeps renewing his old requirements over and over. How do i get it to so that when the subscription renews it uses the latest custom field data found inside the account area?

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEMpY.png

This is what i have at the moment. In this example below, I tried to copy the user meta to the order meta and update it when the subscription renews. For some reason it's not updating. Perhaps this is the wrong way all together. My PHP is very limited. Can anyone advise?

```
// update subscription meta order
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete','subscription_renew');
function subscription_renew( $order_id ) {

   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // get the order id
   $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); // get the user id

   if ( $order->get_total() > 1 ) {  // not sure why this is here

   $getsend = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'send' ); // grab the user meta field 'send'
   $getcategories = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'categories' ); // grab the user meta field 'categories'

      // now do the update
      $order->update_meta_data( $user_id, 'send', $getsend ); // update user order meta field 'send'
      $order->update_meta_data( $user_id, 'categories', $getcategories ); // update user order meta field 'categories'
      $order_id = $order->save(); // save the order

      return $order_id;

   }

}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. You should remove `$user_id` argument from:

```
  // now do the update
  $order->update_meta_data( $user_id, 'send', $getsend ); // update user order meta field 'send'
  $order->update_meta_data( $user_id, 'categories', $getcategories ); // update user order meta field 'categories'
```

replacing by:

```
  // now do the update
  $order->update_meta_data( 'send', $getsend ); // update user order meta field 'send'
  $order->update_meta_data( 'categories', $getcategories ); // update user order meta field 'categories'
```

Now it should better works.

---

**Update** related to `woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete` hook:

It seems when looking [to the docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#section-1) and to some other code examples, that this hook has 2 arguments: `$subscription` and `$last_order` *(but not `$order_id`)*.

Here is a different code version that should really work, adding to the last related renewal Order, your custom user data as order meta data:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete', 'add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta', 10, 2 );
function add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta( $subscription, $last_order ) {
    if( ! $subscription ) 
        return;

    $user_id = $last_order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id

    if( $send = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'send', true ) ) {
        $last_order->update_meta_data( 'send', $send );
    }

    if( $categories = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'categories', true ) ) {
        $last_order->update_meta_data( 'categories', $categories );
    }

    if( isset($send) || isset($categories) ) {
        $last_order->save();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

Comment: Great! Thank you. This works but only when you renew the order from the admin backend for the customer. When the customer renews the order from the front end, it doesn't work. Why is this?

Comment: @Knights I don't know what could be the hook for customer renews, but I have added an update to my answer as there is some other wrong things in your code.