# Add user meta data as order meta on WooCommerce order status change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am trying to add a custom user meta field to the order meta data.
And I want to add this when I am changing my order status to "wordt-verwerkt" which is a custom order status I added with the WooCommerce plugin for custom order statuses.
I tried to use the code [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62329857/10362452), but I am getting an error when I change my order status.
(I also tried it with the status "processing", and didn't have any success neither)

What I have now is the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wordt-verwerkt', 'add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta', 10, 2 );
function add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta( $order, $data ) {

    $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id

    if( $WefactEmail = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'KVK_nummer_2', true ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'WeFact_email', $WefactEmail );
    }

    if( isset($WefactEmail) ) {
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code (the hooked function arguments are wrong).

See the related source code for this composite hook located in `WC_Order` `status_transition()` method *(on [line 363](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-order.php#L363))*:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_' . $status_transition['to'], $this->get_id(), $this );
```

where `$this` is **`$order`** *(the `WC_Order` Object)* and `$this->get_id()` is **`$order_id`** *(the order Id)*.

Use instead the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wordt-verwerkt', 'add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta', 10, 2 );
function add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta( $order_id, $order ) {
    $user_id  = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id
    $wf_email = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'KVK_nummer_2', true );

    if( ! empty($wf_email) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'WeFact_email', $wf_email );
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

or also this works too:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wordt-verwerkt', 'add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta', 10, 2 );
function add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta( $order_id, $order ) {
    $user_id  = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id
    $wf_email = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'KVK_nummer_2', true );

    if( ! empty($wf_email) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'WeFact_email', $wf_email );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). both should work.

For `processing` status, replace:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wordt-verwerkt', 'add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta', 10, 2 );
```

with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'add_order_meta_from_custom_user_meta', 10, 2 );
```